# Ignore default ports for issuer validation with identity server

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I use IdentityServer4 with an ASP.NET Core API, both hosted in the same API and IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation as and authentication scheme.

It works great so far but an user of mine uses an external tool to request tokens and has not full control over each http request.

This tool request the token from `https://domain:443/identity-server/...` but all other clients do not include the default port.

I inspected the JWT token and it includes the url with port as an issuer.

The request fails then with: `Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10205: Issuer validation failed.`

Is there a way to ignore the port?

Comment: You can turn off issuer validation in general. If not an option, you might need to implement custom token validator.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it in a different way. I created a middleware which cleans the port from the host:

````
public class CleanupHostMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;

        public CleanupHostMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            this.next = next;
        }

        public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            var request = context.Request;

            if (request.Host.HasValue && (HasHttpsPort(request) || HasHttpPort(request)))
            {
                request.Host = new HostString(request.Host.Host);
            }

            return next(context);
        }

        private static bool HasHttpPort(HttpRequest request)
        {
            return request.Scheme == "http" && request.Host.Port == 80;
        }

        private static bool HasHttpsPort(HttpRequest request)
        {
            return request.Scheme == "https" && request.Host.Port == 443;
        }
    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Issuer validation can be turned off on the client side or you can configure static issuer name on the ids4 side in `AddIdentityServer` so that it stops being inferred from the host when the tokens get requested.

[Identity Server Docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/options.html)